# Proof that $\frac{d}{dx}\sin(ax+b) = a\cos(ax+b)$ by first principles

Tags: calculus

I have been trying to prove that the deriative of  $\sin(ax+b)$ is equal to $\:a\cos(ax+b)$. I tried to use the first principle to prove for $\sin(2x)$ and it has worked using the sum to product identity.
I tried to use the sum to product identity to prove a general term of $\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}$ by first principle with the sum to product rule but it hasn't worked.

How can this be proven by first principle? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What does “first principles” mean here? What kind of tools are you willing to use? Clearly not the chain rule, so what?

Comment: (You’ll have a hard time using just sums and differences unless your $a$ happens to be rational; how would you express $\sin(\sqrt{2}x))$ as a sine of sums, for example?

Comment: You mean the definition of the derivative? Don't use any trig identities at all (other than $\sin(\alpha+\beta)$, of course, once you get the definition of the derivative). Just remember how you did things like $$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\sin 5h}h.$$

Comment: @ArturoMagidin "derivative by first principles" means $$f'(x)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$

Comment: @RhysHughes: That’s one interpretations; I’d prefer for the OP to make clear what they mean.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x) = \sin(ax+b)$.
$$\begin{align*} f'(x) &= \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\sin(a(x+h)+b) - \sin(ax+b)}{h}\\
&= \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\sin(ax+b + ah) - \sin(ax+b)}{h}\\
&= \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{2\cos\left(ax+b + \frac{ah}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{ah}{2}\right)}{h}\\
&= \lim_{h\to 0}\cos\left(ax+b + \frac{ah}{2}\right)\cdot \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{2a\sin\left(\frac{ah}{2}\right)}{ah}\\
&= \cos(ax+b)\cdot a\cdot \lim_{ah/2\to 0}\frac{\sin\left(\frac{ah}{2}\right)}{ah/2}\\
&= a\cos(ax+b)
\end{align*}$$

Comment: @ArturoMagidin thanks for the edit. Could you point me to a reference which can be followed for best practices in latex?

Comment: Right click on good examples to see the code, and imitate.